# What is a good SVN client for monitoring commits and viewing changesets etc?

Tags: svn

I am looking for recommendations for a SVN client that is less oriented towards the actual act of developing code and committing changesets like most clients, and more oriented towards monitoring a teams SVN activity, browsing source code, looking at commit diffs / changesets etc. A bonus feature would be realtime notification of commits but as long as I can see a list of recent commits and the username and time, and then click on it to see the changeset, that would be cool.

Thanks

Comment: [UpSource](https://www.jetbrains.com/upsource/) is a great tool for monitoring. It goes a bit farther with options to comment on commits, do code reviews and so on, so it may be an overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Changelists](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.changelists.html) are strictly a client-side organizational tool, so there's no monitoring you can do there.

If you're on Windows, there's [CommitMonitor](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor.html)

There are numerous web-based repository viewers like [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/) and [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/); some of the "packaged solutions" like [Subversion Edge](http://www.collab.net/products/subversion) and [UberSVN](http://www.wandisco.com/ubersvn) bundle repository viewers and management tools together.

The best "monitoring" you can do, though, is talking to your team & discussing what they're working on.

Answer (score 1):

- [Vercue](http://www.vercue.com/) is good commit-monitor even in Free Edition (and *excellent* in Professional)
- [WebSVN](http://www.websvn.info/) is good RO-frontend to SVN-repos (local and remote) without overloading by unrelated functions